# Its possible to hide custom actions based on that feature activation?

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-actions

I've created a Sharepoint context menu custom action and I want to display the it when the feature is activated.

how can i do this ?

Code:

```
<CustomAction RegistrationType="rt1" RegistrationId="0x010100EB674074C71B4AA7BA42EF61F36ADA2E"
Id="CDocuemnt"
Rights="EditListItems"
Description="CDocument"
ImageUrl="Version.gif"
Title="CDocument"
Location="EditControlBlock"
RequireSiteAdministrator="FALSE"
Sequence="428">
    <UrlAction Url="javascript:__doPostBack('project.Document.CDocument','{ItemId}#{ListId}');"></UrlAction>
  </CustomAction>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a several options:

1. Develop a WSP solution package to deploy a feature with the custom action. See [Adding a Custom Action to a Display Form for List Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh500259(v=office.14).aspx)
2. [Create a SharePoint Add-ins that deploys the custom action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163954.aspx).
3. Provision the custom action with code using CSOM.
4. Provision the custom action with PowerShell using the [Add-PnpCustomAction](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/AddPnPCustomAction.md) cmdlet in the PNP framework.

However, it's only the first option that'll give you a feature. However, it'll only work with SharePoint on-premises if you create a farm solution. For SharePoint Online you'll need to develop it as a sandbox solution. They still work as long as they do not contain code.